Widget is not rebuilding using the Flutter Signals package
Im using the following signal package. Here is the link to the specfic [Widget].(https://github.com/kreezen/sport_outside/blob/main/lib/view/add_sportplace/add_sportplace_widget.dart) The widget should rebuild everytime the signal changes state by calling
the watch extension.
Widget:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:signals/signals_flutter.dart';
import 'package:sportoutside/main.dart';
import 'package:sportoutside/view/add_sportplace/carousel_widget.dart';

class AddSportPlaceWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const AddSportPlaceWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var imageFiles = cameraStore.of(context).imageFiles..watch(context);
    var imageErr = cameraStore.of(context).imageError;

    imageErr.listen(context, () {
      if (imageErr.value != null) {
        var errTxt = imageErr.value.toString();
        final messenger = ScaffoldMessenger.of(context);
        messenger.hideCurrentSnackBar();
        messenger.showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(content: Text(errTxt)),
        );
      }
    });

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("Add Sport Place"),
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
          children: [
            Stack(
              children: [
                imageFiles.value.isNotEmpty
                    ? CarouselWidget(imageFiles: imageFiles.value)
                    : FillerImg(),
                Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  height: 300,
                  child: Column(children: [
                    Text(
                      "Select form gallery or camera",
                      textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 22,
                          color: Colors.orangeAccent,
                          background: Paint()..color = Colors.white),
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.file_copy_outlined,
                              color: Colors.orangeAccent),
                          iconSize: 50,
                          onPressed: () {
                            cameraStore.of(context).galleryImage();
                          },
                        ),
                        IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.camera_alt_outlined,
                              color: Colors.orangeAccent),
                          iconSize: 50,
                          onPressed: () {
                            cameraStore.of(context).cameraImage();
                          },
                        ),
                      ],
                    )
                  ]),
                )
              ],
            )
          ],
        )));
  }
}

class FillerImg extends StatelessWidget {
  const FillerImg({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      height: 300,
      child: Image.network(
        "https://picsum.photos/200/300",
        fit: BoxFit.fill,
      ),
    );
  }
}

camerestore:
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:signals/signals_flutter.dart';
import 'package:sportoutside/data/datasource/camera/camera_service.dart';

class CameraStore {
  final CameraService _cameraService = CameraService();
  final imageFiles = Signal<List<XFile>>([]);
  final imageError = Signal<Exception?>(null);

  CamereStore() {
    _handleLostData();
  }

  void cameraImage() async {
    final imageFile = await _cameraService.pickImage(ImageSource.camera);
    if (imageFile != null) {
      imageFiles.value.add(imageFile);
    }
  }

  void galleryImage() async {
    final imageFile = await _cameraService.pickImage(ImageSource.gallery);
    if (imageFile != null) {
      imageFiles.value.add(imageFile);
    }
  }

  void deleteImg(int index) {
    imageFiles.value.removeAt(index);
  }

  void _handleLostData() async {
    final LostDataResponse response = await _cameraService.getLostData();

    if (response.isEmpty) {
      return;
    }
    final List<XFile>? files = response.files;
    if (files != null) {
      imageFiles.value.addAll(files);
    } else {
      imageError.value = response.exception;
    }
  }
}

I know it has something to do with async method calling. You can rewrite the camerastore using AsyncSignal. It will work but it doesnt seem the right way to me.
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:signals/signals_flutter.dart';
import 'package:sportoutside/data/datasource/camera/camera_service.dart';

class CameraStore {
  final CameraService _cameraService = CameraService();
  final imageFiles = AsyncSignal<List<XFile>>(AsyncData([]));
  final imageError = Signal<Exception?>(null);

  CamereStore() {
    _handleLostData();
  }

  void cameraImage() async {
    final imageFile = await _cameraService.pickImage(ImageSource.camera);
    if (imageFile != null) {
      var oldList = imageFiles.value.value ?? [];
      imageFiles.value = AsyncData([...oldList, imageFile]);
    }
  }

  void galleryImage() async {
    final imageFile = await _cameraService.pickImage(ImageSource.gallery);
    if (imageFile != null) {
      var oldList = imageFiles.value.value ?? [];
      imageFiles.value = AsyncData([...oldList, imageFile]);
    }
  }

  void deleteImg(int index) async {
    var rList = imageFiles.value.value ?? [];
    rList.removeAt(index);
    imageFiles.value = AsyncData([...rList]);
  }

  void _handleLostData() async {
    final LostDataResponse response = await _cameraService.getLostData();

    if (response.isEmpty) {
      return;
    }
    final List<XFile>? files = response.files;
    if (files != null) {
      imageFiles.value = AsyncData([...imageFiles.value.value ?? [], ...files]);
    } else {
      imageError.value = response.exception;
    }
  }
}

widget:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:signals/signals_flutter.dart';
import 'package:sportoutside/main.dart';
import 'package:sportoutside/view/add_sportplace/carousel_widget.dart';

class AddSportPlaceWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const AddSportPlaceWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var imageFiles = cameraStore.of(context).imageFiles..watch(context);
    var imageErr = cameraStore.of(context).imageError..watch(context);

    imageErr.listen(context, () {
      if (imageErr.value != null) {
        final messenger = ScaffoldMessenger.of(context);
        messenger.hideCurrentSnackBar();
        messenger.showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(content: Text(imageErr.value.toString())),
        );
      }
    });

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("Add Sport Place"),
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
          children: [
            Stack(
              children: [
                imageFiles.value.maybeMap<Widget>(
                    orElse: () => FillerImg(),
                    data: (value) => CarouselWidget(imageFiles: value)),
                Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  height: 300,
                  child: Column(children: [
                    Text(
                      "Select form gallery or camera",
                      textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 22,
                          color: Colors.orangeAccent,
                          background: Paint()..color = Colors.white),
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.file_copy_outlined,
                              color: Colors.orangeAccent),
                          iconSize: 50,
                          onPressed: () {
                            cameraStore.of(context).galleryImage();
                          },
                        ),
                        IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.camera_alt_outlined,
                              color: Colors.orangeAccent),
                          iconSize: 50,
                          onPressed: () {
                            cameraStore.of(context).cameraImage();
                          },
                        ),
                      ],
                    )
                  ]),
                )
              ],
            )
          ],
        )));
  }
}

class FillerImg extends StatelessWidget {
  const FillerImg({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      height: 300,
      child: Image.network(
        "https://picsum.photos/200/300",
        fit: BoxFit.fill,
      ),
    );
  }
}


